# jQuery: Fade not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, when I call jQuery's fade effect, it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

This function does everything it is supposed to, aside from the fading. It gets called at the correct time.

```
function move_to_term(original_course, helper, term) {

    var cloned_course = original_course.clone(true);

    original_course.addClass('already-scheduled').droppable("destroy");

    helper.fadeOut(function() {
        cloned_course.appendTo(term).attr('style', '').fadeIn("slow");
    });

    cloned_course.draggable();
}
```

**UPDATE:** It fails in both FF 3.5.9 and IE 8.

**UPDATE 2:**

This function is set to be a callback for a droppable's `drop` event:

```
        var new_term = $(sprintf('<li class="term"><strong>%s</strong></li>', term["fields"]["name"]));

        new_term.data('pk', term['pk']);

        new_term.droppable({
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                move_to_term(ui.draggable, ui.helper, $(this));
            },
            accept: function(draggable) {
                return legal_for_term(draggable, $(this))
            },
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            activeClass: 'legal-drop-term-active',
            hoverClass: 'legal-drop-term-hover'
        });
```

**UPDATE 3**: The text does take a little while to change places, as if the fade is happening but just not being animated? Or maybe I'm totally off on that.

**UPDATE 4:** This works just fine, although it doesn't accomplish the effect I'd hoped for:

```
function moveToTerm(original_course, helper, term) {

    original_course.fadeOut('slow');

}
```

Here is the droppable HTML:

```
<li class="term ui-droppable">
      <strong>Fall 2010</strong>
      <li class="course">Computing Cultures</li>
</li>
```

Here is the draggable HTML:

```
<li class="course ui-draggable">Introduction to Web Design</li>
```

Is fading not supported on `ui.helper` objects?

**UPDATE 5**: Ok, now all I want to do is to fade in the cloned object:

```
function moveToTerm(original_course, helper, term) {

    var cloned_course = original_course.clone(true);

    original_course.addClass('already-scheduled');

    original_course.draggable("disable");
    cloned_course.draggable();

    cloned_course.appendTo(term).fadeIn("slow");
}
```

This doesn't work, but changing `fadeIn()` to `fadeOut()` makes it work. Why?

**FIXED:**

Change:

```
    cloned_course.appendTo(term).fadeIn("slow");
```

to:

```
    cloned_course.appendTo(term).hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: Without any knowledge of what you're passing in here, this is impossible to answer...

Comment: *"Could it be because of the code?"* I daresay, as jQuery's `fadeIn` isn't just fundamentally broken. A bit more context, as Nick says, would be key to getting help. A minimalist failing test case, for instance.

Comment: Which fade wasn't working? Is there any chance that you are appending the clone of the element into the same container as the original? If so, and if the original has absolute positioning, then could it be that they are essentially stacked, therefore obscuring the effect of the fade?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
helper.fadeOut('slow', function() {
    cloned_course.appendTo(term).attr('style', '').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

> Could it be because of the code?

Jquery library's code, no, it couldn't (of course).

Without know how the context of execution of your code, I can't give any more help.

Comment: That shouldn't be it. `fadeOut()` will work fine taking a callback as the only parameter.

Comment: @patrick is correct - `.fadeOut(func)` is really ``.animate({ opacity: "hide" }, func)`, [which is handled](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would try calling it without the `attr('style', '')` call. I would imagine that could definetely interfere with fade, since fade works by setting inline css of `opacity` (plus some further magic for ie).

## Edit

It's hard to tell (since I can't really test it and the description could be clearer). Wouldn't chaining in a `hide()` help?

```
cloned_course.appendTo(term).attr('style', '').hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: That shouldn't be it. `attr('style','')` is called on a separate element. There wouldn't be any cross-effect.

Comment: @patrick: *"[It's] called on a separate element"* It is? Looks chained to me, whatever `attr` is being applied to is also what `fadeIn` is being applied to. Not saying Jakub's right that that's what's wrong, but...

Comment: Yeah removing `.attr('style', '')` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - You (and Jakub Hampl) are (potentially) right. I somehow assumed the OP was talking about the `.fadeOut()`. Since the OP says it is doing everything right, except fading, it would seem safe to assume that the initial fade required for the callback isn't working. Unclear though. Thanks for the correction, though.

Comment: It would help if you could add a minimum reasonable version into something like http://jsbin.com and paste a link.